# Laravel creating tables error

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
vagrant@homestead:~/www/laravel$ php artisan migrate
```

When I run the code does not create the latest database table.

Worked:

- roles
- permissions
- permission_role

Error:

- role_user

[image]

This I encode my database migration ..

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRolePermissions extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('label');
            $table->timestamps();

        });

        Schema::create('permissions', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('label');
            $table->timestamps();

        });

        Schema::create('permission_role', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigined();
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigined();

            $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->referance('id')
                ->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('permission_id')
                ->referance('id')
                ->on('permissions')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['role_id', 'permission_id']);

        });

        Schema::create('role_user', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigined();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigined();

            $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->referance('id')
                ->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->referance('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);

        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        \DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');

        Schema::drop('roles');
        Schema::drop('permissions');
        Schema::drop('permission_role');
        Schema::drop('role_user');

        \DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');

    }
}
```

I would be glad if you help me I solve this problem a long time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `->references()`, but not `->referance()`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: Hi Alexy,  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
  : alter table `permission_role` add constraint `permission_role_role_id_for
  eign` foreign key (`role_id`) references `roles` (`id`))
and 
  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint Thank you

Comment: Thank you, and ->unsigined() to ->unsigned() :) thank you for help